# Post array using Form Data to C# WebAPI using AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I want to post an array with some files using FormData to WebAPI however it is showing [Object%Object] on Webapi. Please help me out of this. Appricieted in advance. below is the code snippet:

```
        var arr = [];
        var table = $('#tblOptionType');
        var tr = table.find('tbody tr');
        tr.each(function (i, v) {
            if (i != 0) {
                var values = {
                    Options: $(v)[0].cells[0].firstElementChild.value,
                    IsCorrect: $(v)[0].cells[1].firstElementChild.checked,
                };
                arr.push(values);
            }
        });
        formData = new FormData();
        jQuery.each(jQuery('#QuestionImage')[0].files, function (i, file) {
                 formData.append('file-' + i, file);
        });                 
        formData.append("Options", arr);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:56892/api/Admin/Questions/AddQuestion',
            method: "POST",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            traditional: true,
            success: function (res) {}
            error:function(err){}
        });
```

Here is the string i am receiving on the WebAPI:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `contentType` which is type of data you're sending, so `application/json; charset=utf-8` is a common one, as is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`, which is the default:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:56892/api/Admin/Questions/AddQuestion',
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(formData),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        processData: false,
        traditional: true,
        success: function (res) {}
        error:function(err){}
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response however via this code, the method type is getting changed to 'OPTIONS' as this is cross-origin request. Please let me know how to handle this.

Comment: I could not understand but it seems it is not about this question. Have a look at [ajax-request-with-custom-header-sent-to-web-api-server-with-cors-enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29210299/ajax-request-with-custom-header-sent-to-web-api-server-with-cors-enabled) it may help